# Is there a way to get all facebook ads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I need to get all ads from Facebook API. Is there a way to do it?

Here a example of what i need https://adspyhub.com/

This is for a app that i'm developing in React JS.
I'd already read the docs, but i'm not finding anything.
I'm using react-facebook-login to Facebook Login

```
 <FacebookLogin
        appId="************"
        autoLoad={true}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        scope="public_profile,user_friends,user_actions.books"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("clic");
        }}
        callback={response => {
          const axios = require("axios");
          axios.get(
            `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/ads_archive?access_token=${
              response.accessToken
            }&ad_reached_countries=${["US"]}`
          );
        }}
      />
```

This error appears as response for Axios Request. What permissions I need to do this?

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
      "error_subcode": 2332002,
      "is_transient": false,
      "error_user_title": "Authorization and login needed",
      "error_user_msg": "For access to the API you need to be authorized and logged into Facebook.To begin authorization, you can visit facebook.com/ID.",
      "fbtrace_id": "*********"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find any "ads_archive" endpoint in the API reference, you may want to take at the existing ones: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v3.3

The first endpoint i would try is `/adaccounts` to get all Ad Accounts. For every Ad Account, you can get Campaigns, AdSets, Ads, ... for example: `/ad-account-id/adsets`

Also, you do not ask for permissions related to Ads: `ads_read` and `ads_management`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! With this information can I get all ads accounts or just my ads?

Comment: the answer to that comment is actually in my answer already, with the neccessary endpoint ;) - or did i misunderstand?

Comment: Sorry by my english. I'm brazillian and not text very well. You're right! You saved me man, thanks!